# ASP.NET - Lost access to stylesheet and JS after doing SVN update to previous revision

Tags: asp.net, svn, iis-7, asp.net-membership

I am having the strangest behaviour. I recently did a SVN update to an older revision so I could debug something and I lost access to my main stylesheet which is located in a styles folder eg:

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However I can still access (which is located in the same directory):

```
<link href="/styles/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I also found that I could access all of my javascript files located at:

```
/scripts/<my javascript files>
```

until I did a second update to a previous revision, and now I cant access

```
/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js
```

but I can still access the other scripts in the same directory!! By not being able to access them I mean that I get redirected to the log in. ASP.NET Membership seems to be looking for authorisation to access these files. ie

```
http://localhost/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fstyles%2fmain.css
```

I am using RBA but not in these directories. My page source looks like this:

```
<link href="/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/styles/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/spin.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/js.js"></script>
```

and I find it strange that its only the first css and js file that are being blocked.

Just to reiterate, this has worked fine until I did the SVN Update To Revision. Updating to Head revision afterwards does not fix the problem. Furthermore I have this application deployed and it works fine.

Explicitly setting access in the web.config does nothing....

```
<location path="styles/main.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

If someone has an idea I would be most grateful. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Setting

```
<roleManager enabled="false">
```

does not fix the problem.

Comment: Just curious: did you update a _section_ of your checkout to revision xyz or did you update the entire checkout? If it's the former, then you might have different versions of files across the checkout and some files at, say HEAD reference other files that don't exist yet because the folder they would be placed in is at revision xyz instead of HEAD. The fix: update the _entire_ checkout to HEAD, do an `svn cleanup`, Windows-delete any unversioned files, `svn update` again, then `svn update` to revision xyz.

Comment: @SameerSingh - I updated the entire checkout. Thanks though.

Comment: It seems as though this is IIS related. If I run the project in the VS Dev Server instead of the Local IIS Webserver the problem disappears. Setting allowOverride="false" doesn't solve the problem though

Comment: Time to go knocking at IIS and clear caches (including browser caches) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have permission issue after updateing the working copy to previous revision.

Change the permission for your project root directory/ or the directory of concern  as follows.

```
1.Right Click -> properties -> Edit permission Tab
2.Look fir IIS_User or I_User or NetworkService object in the permission window.
3.If this object is not found add a new Object "EveryOne".
4.Edit permission for that object and  select(all permission for development machine).
5.Done now try to access.
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately IIS_IUSRS has full permissions.